# Change the default value of the "Startup directory for new process" in the "Create new console" dialog

Tags: conemu

How do we change the default value for the **Startup directory for new process?** Out of the box the default is my user directory `C:\Users\bigfo`.

[image]

My current workaround is to change the `{Bash::bash}` task so that it overrides whatever is in the **Create new console** dialog. I do that like this:

> set "PATH=%ConEmuBaseDirShort%\wsl;%PATH%" & %ConEmuBaseDirShort%\conemu-cyg-64.exe --wsl  -cur_console:pm:/mnt  **-new_console:d:C:\dev**

What I would really like, though, is for the **Create new console** dialog to look like this:

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use "New console dialog"? Why don't run certain Tasks immediately?

Comment: @Maximus I haven't learned the shortcuts for that yet. Perhaps I should learn the shortcuts to run certain Tasks immediately.

Answer (score 1):

## conemu & cmder default startup locations:

*there are actually two answers for this question depending on what you
*really* want to do.  i will list both:*

### the global *default startup path*

for all tasks this is set at launch time from the cli or, more commonly, the
windows startup link from the **start menu** or **taskbar**.  in either case,
you can edit this from the default, which is typically set to the install
folder.

- if changing a start menu link, begin at the desktop, press `oskey` to bring
  up the start menu.  assuming cortana is active, you can simply search for
  `cmder` by typing it out.  if not, you will have to scroll down to find your
  link to cmder or conemu.
- `right-click` on the icon, select `open file location` from the context menu.
- after windows explorer opens, the shortcut to the program will be
  highlighted.  right-click this shortcut and select `properties` from the context
  menu.
- - ***note:*** it is possible that the application location rather than a
    shortcut will be highlighted.  if it is an application, right-click the
    program and select `pin to taskbar` from the context menu.  then skip down
    to the part about setting the taskbar shortcut default folder.
    it is also possible to select `pin to start menu` but this method requires
    that you then navigate to
    `\programdata\microsoft\windows\start menu\programs\` and edit the
    shortcut.  otherwise, the process will be identical to the taskbar step.
- the first page/general options in properties will have the path to the
  program first, and the startup folder second.  simply change the startup
  location to your desired path (typically `c:\users\<yourname>`).
- video of process: [image]

### The per-task method (override the global default):

*NOTE: this is if you want a specific task or several specific tasks to open in
a place other than the global default.*

- If Cmder/ConEmu is not running, start it.
- From within any terminal, press `winkey+alt+p` to open the settings.
- In settings on the left side nested tree navigation locate to
  `Startup->Tasks`.
- Scroll down to find the task you wish to edit.
- In the large edit box, place the input cursor at the end and press the
  `Startup dir...` button to add the startup location CLI option to the
  startup command for this task.
- Navigate to the folder you wish to start the application in.  If it's not
  something you can navigate to, simply select any folder and edit it after
  you're done in the launch command.
- Video:[image]